# nested mybatis map

Tags: java, mybatis

I cannot figure out how to use mybatis results in a complex object.

I have the following mapper class:

```
public interface StationMapper {
   @MapKey("stationId")
   Map<Integer,Station> getStations();
}
```

which is built from the following resultMap:

```
<resultMap id="stationMap" type="Station">
   <result column="station_id" property="stationId" />
   <result column="another_id" property="notUniqueId" />
   <result column="name" property="name" />
</resultMap>
```

Instead of a map, I'd like the return type for getStations() to be an object which takes the map (or a collection) as a constructor so that I can execute some code on object construction.

```
public class FancyStationMapHolder {
   public FancyStationMapHolder(Map<Integer,Station> stations) {
      executeSpecialCode(stations);
   }
   // OR
   public FancyStationMapHolder(Collection<Station> stations) {
      executeSpecialCode(stations);
   }
}
public interface StationMapper {
   FancyStationMapHolder getStations();
}
```

I don't think I can use the <resultMap> <collection> element (and I've tried) because there is no actual data relationship.

Alternately, I'd like a StationMapper method with this signature:

```
@MapKey("notUniqueId")
Map<String,Collection<Station>> getStationsByNotUniqueId();
```

**Edit:**
I can get this complex object if I restrict it based on some column and set a property rather than use a constructor, but how can I do it without the relational restriction?

```
<resultMap id="fancyMap" type="sample.FancyStationMapHolder">
  <result column="someId" property="someId"/>
  <collection property="stations" column="someId" resultMap="stationMap"
   select="stations" javaType="ArrayList" />
</resultMap>
```

I prefer to use the constructor, so I'd appreciate advice on that as well. The following  setup results in this Exception:

```
 org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException:
 nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException:
 Error instantiating class sample.FancyStationMapHolder with invalid types
     (ArrayList,) or values ([...

<resultMap id="fancyMap" type="sample.FancyStationMapHolder">
  <constructor>
    <arg column="someId" resultMap="stationMap" select="stations"
         javaType="ArrayList" />
  </constructor>
  <result column="someId" property="someId"/>
</resultMap>
```

Answer (score 2):

MyBatis does a great job of mapping columns to POJO attributes and does a little bit of extra work for fancier mappings. But in general I would advice against trying to put your business logic into mapping / marshalling via MyBatis. I travelled this road myself and mostly got what I needed out of the mappers, but later removed all of it.

So, simply get `List<Station>` from your mapper method and convert it to the desired model in a private converter method placed in your DAO or Controller or Service that needs this stuff. It is almost always better to cover mappers with at least one abstraction layer that combines multiple updates into single transactions, handles optimistic locks, hides internal helper containers, advanced caching logic etc.

One benefit is, such code will be easier to maintain, and the next developer does not have to dive into the peculiarities of MyBatis mapping. Also, grabbing `List<Station>` also allows to re-use the same query for other purposes, cache it reasonably well etc.

If `List<Station>` takes too much resources and query is on a critical performance path, use MyBatis ResultHandler to iterate over JDBS ResultSet.