# Can Mybatis annotation mappers return arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, select, mybatis

I would like to return an array from an annotation based Mybatis mapper to avoid the memory overhead of boxed primitives. Is this possible?

I tried

```
@Select("select id from some_table")
public long[] selectIds();
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

**MyBatis mapper can return array of Object,but not array of primitives**

please see the example below:-

```
@Results({
    @Result(property = "id", column = "id"),
    @Result(property = "name", column = "name"),
    @Result(property = "staffNumber", column = "staff_number")
  })    
@Select("select * from USERS")
User[] finduserArr();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @MapKey annotation. It produces a Map with id as key and a Hashmap (key = column Name, value = value) as value

Check [nested mybatis map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274539/nested-mybatis-map) for further reference

Answer (score 0):

It can as of version 3.1. Try with 3.1.1.